# Remove prefix text from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Remove CLBeacon text from the prefix of every data from an array

> "CLBeacon (uuid:F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E, major:20310, minor:48417, proximity:0 +/- -1.00m, rssi:0)",

I want to remove CLBeacon text and inside data want to add to an array.

Comment: what do you mean of remove CLBeancon text?

Comment: It looks like the output of the implicit `description` property of a struct. Why don't you implement your own `description` to return what you want.

Comment: Don't use the `description` value of an object for anything other than debug logging.  Get the properties of the CLBeacon object and build your string

Comment: OK Thanks am first time using CLBeacons

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do this with `map` and `substring`.

```
let prefixText = "CLBeacon"
let prefixCount = prefixText.characters.count
let arrayWithoutPrefixes = array.map { $0.substring(from: $0.characters.index($0.startIndex, offsetBy: prefixCount)) }
```